# golang creating multi level string map

Tags: dictionary, go

I am very new to Go language. I am struggling with following usecase.

I want to store session id (string) and reqeust No (string) in a map for duplicate checking. When there is no entry in the map, it should create one, else it should return a flag saying the entry already exists.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    mySessionData := make(map[string]map[string]bool)

    var ret bool
    ret = chkDuplicate(mySessionData, "session1", "1")
    fmt.Println(mySessionData)
    ret = chkDuplicate(mySessionData, "session1", "2")
    fmt.Println(mySessionData)
    ret = chkDuplicate(mySessionData, "session1", "3")
    fmt.Println(mySessionData)
    ret = chkDuplicate(mySessionData, "session1", "2")
    fmt.Println(mySessionData)
    ret = chkDuplicate(mySessionData, "session1", "4")
    fmt.Println(mySessionData)
    fmt.Println(ret)

    delete(mySessionData, "session1")
    fmt.Println(mySessionData)

}

func chkDuplicate(m map[string]map[string]bool, sess string, Reqno string) bool {
    var found bool
    val, found := m[sess][Reqno]
    if !found {
        fmt.Println(val)
        valu := make(map[string]bool)
        valu[Reqno] = true
        m[sess] = valu
        return !found

    }
    return !found
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the value is over written every time the function is called. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you're creating a new map each time found is false, don't do that, check if m[sess] is nil and only then create it, if it's not nil just set m[sess][Reqno] to true. https://play.golang.org/p/VlPY8UmRU-5

Comment: You're not using `val` variable anywhere

Comment: This code will not work as expected since you are creating a new map for `req` every time you check for duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often simpler to use a struct key instead of a multi-level map:
https://play.golang.org/p/WFlGi1rrVOm

Answer (score 1):

You only have to create a value of the inner map (the session map) if a map for the given session ID does not yet exists (and *not* if the given request number is not in it), else you clear any previously stored request numbers from it.

Since you are using `bool` as the value type for the inner map (session map), you can exploit this to write simpler code (indexing a map with a key that is not in it will yield the zero value of the value type, which is `false` for the `bool` type, properly telling the key is not in it):

```
func chkDuplicate(m map[string]map[string]bool, sess string, Reqno string) bool {
    sessMap := m[sess]
    if sessMap == nil {
        m[sess] = map[string]bool{Reqno: true}
        return false
    }

    if sessMap[Reqno] {
        return true
    }
    sessMap[Reqno] = true
    return false
}
```

Testing it:

```
func main() {
    mySessionData := make(map[string]map[string]bool)

    for _, reqNo := range []string{"1", "2", "3", "2", "4"} {
        ret := chkDuplicate(mySessionData, "session1", reqNo)
        fmt.Println(ret, mySessionData)
    }

    delete(mySessionData, "session1")
    fmt.Println(mySessionData)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2yniNYuILlW)):

```
false map[session1:map[1:true]]
false map[session1:map[1:true 2:true]]
false map[session1:map[1:true 2:true 3:true]]
true map[session1:map[2:true 3:true 1:true]]
false map[session1:map[2:true 3:true 4:true 1:true]]
map[]
```

Note that `bool` –although may be small–does require memory. Since we can query if a key is in the map, we may opt to use a value type that requires no memory, such as an empty struct (`struct{}`). With that, it may look like this:

```
func chkDuplicate(m map[string]map[string]struct{}, sess string, Reqno string) bool {
    sessMap := m[sess]
    if sessMap == nil {
        m[sess] = map[string]struct{}{Reqno: struct{}{}}
        return false
    }

    if _, ok := sessMap[Reqno]; ok {
        return true
    }
    sessMap[Reqno] = struct{}{}
    return false
}
```

Testing and result is (almost) the same, try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/M6fRiPiM0g_-).

A word of warning: judging from the example, it looks you want to use this to track if a (web) request has been served previously, where usually multiple goroutines are involved. This solution is **not safe for concurrent use**.

Answer (score 0):

sess variable always equals session1, so you just override value for key session1. You have to have indistinguishable keys.

If you want just check duplicates, just to this:

```
package main 

import "fmt"

func main() {
    mySessionData := make(map[string]bool)

    chkDuplicate(mySessionData, "session1", "1")
    chkDuplicate(mySessionData, "session1", "1")
    chkDuplicate(mySessionData, "session2", "1")
    fmt.Println(mySessionData) # two keys printed
}

func chkDuplicate(m map[string]bool, sess string, Reqno string) bool {
    key := fmt.Sprintf("%s-%s", sess, Reqno)
    _, found := m[key]
    if !found {
       m[key] = true    
    }
   return !found
}
```

Comment: I am looking for something that is similar to Perl Hash of Hash. So variable mySessionData should be able to return value true when I access mySessionData["session1"]["2"] but return nil when say mySessionData["session1"]["6"]